# Wireguard Client Cannot Connect to Server Subnet

Tags: linux, routing, wireguard

I have a working setup of wireguard (Ubuntu 20.04 server, one Ubuntu 20.04 client and one Windows 10 client). I can connect to devices behind the VPN server.

```
VPN Server (EndPoint): 1.2.3.2/32
Public Subnet EndPoint sits in: 1.2.3.0/27
WireGuard Server Address: 10.2.0.1/16
Office LAN: 10.0.0.0/16
Peer Address: 10.2.0.3/16
```

The problem is that the clients cannot connect to anything that should go over the vpn including the EndPoint address when I add the public subnet of the WireGuard public interface to `AllowedIPs` in the client config:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.2.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/16, 1.2.3.0/27
```

OR add the `EndPoint` address:

```
AllowedIPs = 10.2.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/16, 1.2.3.2/32
```

It works when I add other individual addresses from the public subnet. I can connect to those servers over the VPN (traceroute says so):

```
AllowedIPs = 10.2.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/16, 1.2.3.3/32, 1.2.3.4/32
```

Additional Info:

CLIENT

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg1.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <snipped>
Address = 10.2.0.3/16

[Peer]
PublicKey = <snipped>
AllowedIPs = 10.2.0.0/16, 10.0.0.0/16, 1.2.3.3/32, 1.2.3.4/32, 1.2.3.0/27
Endpoint = 1.2.3.2:51820

$ ip route
default via 10.25.0.1 dev wlp0s20f3 proto dhcp metric 600 
10.0.0.0/16 dev wg1 scope link 
10.25.0.0/16 dev wlp0s20f3 proto kernel scope link src 10.25.50.12 metric 600 
10.2.0.0/16 dev wg1 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.3 
1.2.3.0/27 dev wg1 scope link 
1.2.3.3 dev wg1 scope link 
1.2.3.4 dev wg1 scope link

$ sudo tcpdump -nn -i any 'udp port 51820'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
23:21:43.439854 IP 10.2.0.3.34656 > 1.2.3.1.51820: UDP, length 148
23:21:48.705386 IP 10.2.0.3.34656 > 1.2.3.1.51820: UDP, length 148
23:21:54.081297 IP 10.2.0.3.34656 > 1.2.3.1.51820: UDP, length 148
23:21:59.201381 IP 10.2.0.3.34656 > 1.2.3.1.51820: UDP, length 148
```

Traceroute times out.

SERVER

```
$ ip route
default via 1.2.3.1 dev enp1s0 proto static 
10.0.0.0/16 dev enp6s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.25.20 
10.0.0.0/16 via 10.0.1.254 dev enp6s0 proto static metric 100 
10.2.0.0/16 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.1 
1.2.3.0/27 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 1.2.3.2

$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf 
[Interface]
Address = 10.2.0.1/16
SaveConfig = true
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on enp6s0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on enp6s0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp6s0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = <snipped>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <snipped>
AllowedIPs = 10.2.0.2/32
Endpoint = <snipped>:37785

[Peer]
PublicKey = <snipped>
AllowedIPs = 10.2.0.3/32
Endpoint = <snipped>:37950
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have this route on your server:

```
1.2.3.0/27 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 1.2.3.2
```

You need to add some firewall rules to your server that allow the forwarding and masquerading of your `1.2.3.0/27` traffic from `wg0` to `enp1s0`. Some rules similar to what you already have for `enp6s0` will probably work:

```
ufw route allow in on wg0 out on enp1s0
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Note that ufw always allows ping packets to be forwarded, so if you can ping a host but can't access its other network services, it usually means you need to add a ufw rule to grant access.